# What is a viable replacement for Searchlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, searchlogic, meta-search

It appears that [Searchlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) doesn't work with Rails 3. (Among other things, Ryan Bates mentioned in in one of his RailsCasts, and the last question in the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/searchlogic) is from 2010.)

So I'm looking for a replacement. I like the functionality where you craft the field names of a search form and have that get turned into a Search object and then you could get the results with `@search.all` or `@search.paginate`.

At first, [Meta Where](http://erniemiller.org/projects/metawhere/) and [Meta Search](http://erniemiller.org/projects/metasearch/) looked promising. But then I found [this](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) notification that "MetaWhere will not be updated to support 3.1". (I'm using Rails 3.2.2.)

The developer is [proposing a library called "Ransack"](http://erniemiller.org/2011/08/31/rails-3-1-and-the-future-of-metawhere-and-metasearch/#more-978) as the replacement for MetaWhere.

OK, maybe. But before I dive into "Ransack," I thought I'd put the question out there: does anyone know of another library available with similar functionality to SearchLogic as I described above? (View form populates a Search object.)

Comment: https://github.com/ernie/squeel

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the default ActiveRecord query interface? Are you really getting that much of a benefit out of the dynamic finders offered by these gems?

Comment: @Zabba, thanks, but have an closer look at the specifics of my question. Squee does not have the functionality I described.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Rails 3.0 you should check out [MetaSearch](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search)

If you are using Rails 3.1+ you should check out [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack)

Both are written by Ernie Miller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned in my question, I'm using Rails 3.2.2 and I've heard of Ransack. I started checking out Ransack yesterday. So far it seems to work OK. But given the history behind Ransack, I'm still interested in finding out if anyone has experience with a alternative.

Comment: MetaSearch seems to blow up in Rails 3.2.2:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858552/metasearch-gem-rails-3-0-working-scope-methods-fail-in-rails-3-2

Comment: @jpgeek you want to use `ransack` for Rails 3.1+. https://github.com/ernie/ransack